# active directory on Windows 2000: how to give rdp access and telnet acces to user?

Tags: windows, active-directory

I'm running an AD server on Windows 2000(i know is a little old, but is in a private network not connected to internet so is "safe"). I have created a user, it can connect from a pc of the network, but not from telnet or Remote desktop.
How to give access to user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found. I have opened control panel, then domain controller security policy, then local access, and I add my user to user which can access to DC via telnet or rdp(telnet must be restart after the modify).